# Page visit counter

Tags: javascript

The following counts the number of page loads and then does something if < `MIN_PAGE_VIEWS`.

Can anyone give me any pointers to improve both this function and my JavaScript in general? Both in terms of patterns, design and algorithm.

```
// Call on body onload event.
// Checks to see if prompt is to be displayed and if banner is to be displayed.
function bodyOnLoad() { 

    var MIN_PAGE_VIEWS = 3;

    if(readCookie('counter-cookie') == null){   
        createCookie('counter-cookie', '0', '150');
    }

    // Only start showing random popup after second page visit
    if (readCookie('counter-cookie') < MIN_PAGE_VIEWS) { 

        var iCount = parseInt(readCookie('counter-cookie'));
        iCount++;
        createCookie('counter-cookie',iCount.toString(), '150');
    } 
    else{
        if (readCookie('ab5cd57e-871a-4b65') != 'yes') { 
            showPanel('popupPanel',80,240,'yes'); 
        }
    } 

    if(readCookie('banner-cookie') == 'yes'){
        showPanel('surveyBanner',100,100, 'no'); 
        displayBanner();
    }
}

// New Cookie and Set expiration date
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

// Separates cookies
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to improve your JavaScript, run your code through http://www.jslint.com/
Where it complaints about something, try to understand why - more often than not, it is a valid complaint. :)

---

1. Start the JavaScript with `"use strict";`. (That also means you
   should wrap the code in a self-executing function.) There is plenty
   of material out there explaining this much better than I would. :)
2. You should store the result of `readCookie('counter-cookie')` in a
   variable, instead of calling it repeatedly.
3. In `createCookie('counter-cookie',iCount.toString(), '150');`, why
   the `.toString()`?
4. You should use `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=`. They are
   different, and the shorter version should be used sparingly.
5. In `createCookie`, you want `if(typeof days === 'number') { ... }`,
   and to pass in a number (`150`) instead of a string (`'150'`).
6. In `createCookie`, declare the var `expires` at the top of the
   method. In the first branch of the if, you are using a var in the
   global context: Bad Idea<sup>tm</sup>.
7. In `createCookie`, you seem to be overriding all cookies when
   setting the date. Is this on purpose? Or does `document-cookie =
   'foo';` do some black-magic that I am not expecting?
8. In `createCookie` you use `date.toGMTString()` - [in MDN it is advised to use .toUTCString instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
9. In `readCookie`, that indention is hurtful. :|
10. In `readCookie`, do you need to `while(!false) str.substring()`? I
    would try to get the index, and then to a **single** `substring()` op.

Answer (score 1):

- Always declare variables on the first line of their function. They are automatically [hoisted](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/) there anyway, so declaring them anywhere else results in code that is written in a different order than it is executed.
- Keep your formatting consistent. [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) has a particular style that is considered "proper", but obeying their rules exactly is less important than never breaking your own rules.
- Namespace your code. An easy way to do this is to wrap your code in `(function () {/* code here */}());`. The reason you want to do this is so you don't accidentally overwrite other scripts' variables, and so they don't overwrite yours.
- Try to keep results around that you might need again. For example, `readCookie()` currently re-parses `document.cookie` every time it is called, when it really only needs to parse it once, then keep the result around. Of course, then the array isn't updated by `createCookie`, but it doesn't look like your code requires that functionality.
- Be aware of the difference between `===` and `==` - in several cases above, you used the latter when you wanted the former.
- Storing the string `"yes"` to indicate `true` overcomplicates things. I would just set the cookie to `1` (which is automatically converted to `"1"`), then, when testing for it, simply write `if (readCookie('banner-cookie')) {`.
- Some would disagree with me on this one, but I think regular expressions can make your code more readable. They can certainly make it shorter.